# How to set a different time zone for a SPECIFIC task in crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I need to add a new task for crontab which will execute it in a **different** TZ than the local machine time.
I succeed to do it as you can see in the example below, but the problem is that from time i changed the TZ all the jobs after refers to the new TZ

```
    * * * * * rubHello.sh
    0 19 * * * runKuku.sh
    CRON_TZ="Europe/Rome"
    17 13 * * * /tmp/job1.sh
    0  18 * * * /tmp/Job2.sh
```

in the example above, job1 runs in Europe/Rome as my request, but also job2
runs in that time which is NOT OK.

it there a way to tell crontab change the TZ for only specific task and get back to default crontab TZ for the next jobs after?

Thank you.

Comment: Add version of your cron to your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: OP uses `cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64` (according to OP's comment to Martin's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try this (assuming that you're in Istanbul), `CRON_TZ` variable should be set before your cron entry :

```
* * * * * rubHello.sh
0 19 * * * runKuku.sh
CRON_TZ="Europe/Rome"
17 13 * * * /tmp/job1.sh
CRON_TZ="Europe/Istanbul"  
0  18 * * * /tmp/Job2.sh
```

*OR*

```
* * * * * rubHello.sh
0 19 * * * runKuku.sh
0  18 * * * /tmp/Job2.sh
CRON_TZ="Europe/Rome"
17 13 * * * /tmp/job1.sh
```

Comment: sorry, i want to return to the default crontab TZ

Comment: @Asfbar then just try the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I believe:

```
* * * * * rubHello.sh
0 19 * * * runKuku.sh
17 13 * * * TZ="Europe/Rome" /tmp/job1.sh
0  18 * * * /tmp/Job2.sh
```

Comment: Oh :-( Did you try `TZ` or `CRON_TZ`?

Comment: What cron daemon do you have?

Comment: cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64

Comment: OK, but how i can set it back to default ?

Comment: I tested setting the TZ on my Ubuntu machine with (Vixie's cron) the timezone got set.

Not sure if that is enough for you or you need the command to actually be run at the different time according to the timezone. You probably should take the advice by Barbaros.

Comment: If you don't know the default, then take it from `/etc/timezone`.